# How to add mpandroidchart line chart touch point value display with line color

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How to add mpandroidchart line chart touch point value display Marker view with line color background

My expectation

[image]

my coding

```
CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView (MainActivity.this, R.layout.tv_content);
chart.setMarkerView(mv);
```

CustomMarkerView.java

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView {

private TextView tvContent;
public CustomMarkerView (Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);
    // this markerview only displays a textview
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
}

@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    tvContent.setText("" + e.getVal());
}

@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    return -(getWidth() / 2);
}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    return -getHeight();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, @a.g.thamys did you solve this issue ?? I'm trying to do some thing like this.

Comment: Not yet @Tefa, just ask MPChart admin

Comment: Ok,    thank you...